# ¿Por qué no agrega más de un dato en una colección en Java?

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en el foro, espero realizar mi duda de manera clara y sin infringir ninguna norma.

Tengo un problema con `PriorityQueue`, estoy creando una Agenda la cual pueda almacenar `Nombre` y `Número` de alguna persona. Tengo una clase en la cual creo una colección con `PriorityQueue` la cual puede agregar datos a la colección, eliminar y mostrar los datos almacenados. Yo le pido al usuario mediante `Scanner` los nombres y los números de su contacto y cuando leo los datos, almaceno la información recién cedida en la colección, la primer ves que ingresan un contacto sí guarda el contacto a la colección, el problema viene cuando deseo agregar otro contacto ya que no lo guarda, trato de mostrarlos y me imprime el primer contacto pero el segundo me aparece como `null`

Ahora muestro mi código:

Aquí pido al usuario que haga una acción de la lista, si desea agregar un contacto basta con presionar el numero 2. Después entra al case 2 el cual le pide al usuario que ingrese el nombre y número. 
Ahora la función agregarContacto() agrega el nombre y número.

```
System.out.println("¿Qué deseas hacer?");
            System.out.println("1.- Buscar contactos.");
            System.out.println("2.- Agregar contacto.");
            System.out.println("3.- Modificar contacto.");
            System.out.println("4.- Eliminar contacto.");
            int seleccion = entrada.nextInt();
            entrada.nextLine();

            switch (seleccion)
            {
                case 1:
                        Contenedor.imprimirContactitos();
                        break;
                case 2:
                        System.out.println("\nIngresa el nombre de tu contacto... ");
                        String nombre = entrada.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("\nIngresa el número telefonico de tu contacto...");
                        String numero = entrada.nextLine();
                        agregarContactos(nombre,numero);
                        break;
```

Ahora observamos la función agregarContactos(), se construye el objeto añadiendo a la colección el primer contacto ingresado.

```
public static void agregarContactos(String nombre, String numero)
{
    try
    {
        Contactos contacto = new Contactos(nombre,numero);
        Contenedor.agregar(contacto);
        System.out.println("Agregaste a: " +nombre);
        System.out.println("Número de telefono: " +numero);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

En el siguiente bloque de código veremos la función donde agrega un contacto a la colección (que es dónde me tira el error),

```
private static PriorityQueue<Contactos> contactitos = new PriorityQueue();    
    /**
     * Método que permite agregar un contacto a la colección
     */
    public static boolean agregar(Contactos contacto)
    {
    return contactitos.offer(contacto);
}
```

Y esto es lo que me tira de error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: datos.Contactos cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Comparable  at
>   java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:652)  at
>   java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:647)    at
>   java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:344)     at
>   listas.Contenedor.agregar(Contenedor.java:13)     at
>   principal.Main.agregarContactos(Main.java:21)     at
>   principal.Main.mostrarMenu(Main.java:54)  at
>   principal.Main.(Main.java:13)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.lambda$run$1(ExecServer.java:789)     at
>   bluej.runtime.ExecServer.runOnTargetThread(ExecServer.java:913)   at
>   bluej.runtime.ExecServer.access$700(ExecServer.java:78)   at
>   bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:787)

La verdad es que no entiendo porque me pasa, tengo un programa ya creado en el cual hago lo mismo solo que contiene una GUI en donde con cajas de texto y choice yo creo la colección pero acá no me funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según la documentación

> Los elementos de la cola de prioridad se ordenan de acuerdo a `Comparable`
>    o por un `Comparator`, dependiendo del constructor que se utilice. Una
>   cola de prioridad no permite elementos nulos . Una cola de prioridad que
>   depende del ordenamiento natural tampoco permite la inserción de
>   objetos no comparables (puede resultar en ello `ClassCastException`).

Entonces el error se resolvería simplemente con añadir a su clase `Contacto` `implements Comparable<Contacto>` y sobrescribir el método `compareTo` de acuerdo al orden en que desea que se ordenen los elementos. Para el ejemplo se ordena por el atributo número.

```
public class Contacto implements Comparable<Contacto>{
 ....
public Contacto(String nombre, String numero) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.numero = numero;
}

 /* Método sobrescrito*/
 @Override
 public int compareTo(Contacto t) {
    return this.getNumero().compareTo(t.getNumero());
 }

}
```

Además como su método `agregar()` retorna un `boolean`podría emplear para mostrar el mensaje si se insertó o no a la cola.

```
public  void agregarContactos(String nombre, String numero)
{
    try
    {
        Contacto contacto = new Contacto(nombre,numero);
        if(Contenedor.agregar(contacto)){
            System.out.println("Agregaste a: " +nombre);
            System.out.println("Número de telefono: " +numero);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("No se pudo agregar");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Me ganaste, estaba escribiendo esta respuesta :P.

Comment: Buen día. Me sirvió, ahora sí guarda todos los contactos que desee en la colección. Muchas gracias de antemano y ya le di voto positivo jaja. Saludos.